# Outlook App PC and Mac and FROM field

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I would like the FROM field to be "prefilled" when a new message form open by the end user.

Many users have the send as permission for an email address and they send email from this address at 99% of cases. So it's logic to have the FROM field prefilled by default with the send as address.

I have tried a solution several times, but without success.

There is a way to make a new Message form "prefilled" and start it for new messages?
Or a better any way set the from field with a certain value?

Thanks

Comment: Outlook for Windows always uses the Default Email address as the From address in a new Outlook Email. That is for sure. I am not sure about Outlook for MAC but I expect it is similar.

Comment: Agree with John, according to my experience on Outlook for Mac, there may be no option that could change the default address. If you cinfigure some accounts there, it‘s usually sent from the account you choose now.